# Indexing a string from right to left with JavaScript substr function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to a replace a dynamic string from the **end of string** like

```
str = 000000
-------------------------
 index            result
------------------------- 
   0              000001
   1              000010
   2              000100
   3              001000
   4              010000
   5              100000
```

but in this snippet the `substr()` is replanting the str as it is supposed to do from the left to right

```js
var s = "000000";
var index = 0;
s = s.substr(0, index) + '1' + s.substr(index + 1);
$('#app').html(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the position of getting `s.substr(index + 1)` and `s.substr(0, index)`.

```
s = s.substr(index + 1) + '1' + s.substr(0, index);
```

should make it work.

```js
var s = "000000";
var index = 0;
s = s.substr(index + 1) + '1' + s.substr(0, index);
$('#app').html(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply but this somehow is not doing the job on dynamic contents. I tried to demonestrate it at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/e7mcee2j/  As you can see the result at `w` is removing `A` from the begging of the string! and `w1` is not returning any thing

Comment: @Behseini Could you please let me know how it should output like with the contents you've given in demo??

Comment: I am not sure but can you please let me know why the `A` character is omitting from the string while the `F` which was supposed to be replaced with 1 still there!?

Comment: Please also take a look at this demo to see how the original code only replace the character in the index without removing any character from beginning or end http://jsfiddle.net/e7mcee2j/1/

Comment: So it should be removing from leftmost and add remaining to the rightmost after replacing index character?? **[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e7mcee2j/3/)**?